# Trouble Starting Scooter after Replacing Carbeurator

Tags: motorcycle, troubleshooting, carburetor, scooter

## Background

Recently my scooter was having trouble getting up to full speed and was jerking slightly, but only when I gave it a lot of gas or going above around 35 miles an hour. After some research, I came to the conclusion that the problem was likely with the carbuerator, and decided to replace it. I [purchased this one on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008ACXZMK) and put it in.

However, once I got the new carb in, it won't start.

## Attempted Solutions

The chief suspects I have investigated and failed to find issue with have been the following:

- The electric choke. I tried taking off the new choke and replacing it with the one from the old carburetor, which didn't change anything.
- The fuel pump system. I disconnected the fuel line to the carb and hit the starter, which resulted in fuel coming out of the line appropriately.
- According to some internet research, some have luck by just spraying some starting fluid in the carb. I also tried this to no avail. Although its possible I didn't spray enough, as I thought it wise to go too light than too heavy with a highly flammable

## Question

**What other issues are possible with a new carburetor that could prevent it from starting?**

I do not know much about mechanics, but would love to be able to fix it myself. Especially considering I can't find a shop near me who will work on it.

Thank you for any help!

---

#### Scooter Details

Lance (Chinese Manufacturer) 150cc
[Purchased Carburetor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008ACXZMK) (Matches existing carb perfectly from what I can tell.)

Comment: Have you set the mixture and idle screws etc to their base settings, these will be in the manual. The usual type of statement is like the mixture screw needs 1.5 turns anti-clockwise from the closed position initially.